# Is it possible to start tmux visible session

Tags: bash, tmux

The code below will run `source ~/.bashrc` under tmux but this will not open tmux on the terminal.

```
#!/bin/bash
tmux new-session -d -s my_session 'source ~/.bashrc'
```

I want the below effect from the above command:

```
$ tmux
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: you intend to source `~/.bashrc` when inside tmux session? is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yeah. For every time when I run `tmux`, I also need to run `source ~/.bashrc` so that I could use aliases. Here I tried to run `source` command automatically after tmux under tmux.

Comment: ok, so you should add that line to your `.tmux/conf` file.
just `echo "source ./bashrc" >> .tmux/conf` also create that file if it doesn't exit.

Comment: just to add, it's better to source the file from `~/.bash_profile` which is what tmux sources by default if your default shell is bash.

Comment: I don't have `.tmux/conf` I just added the source command in `.tmux.config` below `set -g status-fg white` not working.

Comment: hey, it's `source ~/.bashrc`, i supposed you spotted that! if still didn't work somehow, source it from .bash_profile as i said above. that will do it.

Comment: Thanks, that also help me run aliases on other terminal such as aptana-studio terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmux new-session -d -s my_session
tmux send "source ~/.bashrc" C-m
tmux -2  attach-session -t my_session
```

It should create a new session called `my_session`, excute the command and keep it open.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
#!/bin/tmux
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: I have already tried this.